# Memory editing: Can't get right address (3 offsets)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to change the address of some text in an offline game. 
Writing a string to memory works, tho this code makes me write to a random address in memory.

Process is 64bits. GetModuleBase works fine, I use it to edit some integer values, and it works fine(They have one offset)

Pointer & Offsets works just fine in CheatEngine.

I have tried looking on google, didn't find anything really helping me

```
    HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
    DWORD* adress = (DWORD*)((DWORD*)((DWORD*)((*(DWORD*)(GetModuleBase(GetCurrentProcess(), string("MyGame.exe")) + 0x01E69FD8)) + 0x8) + 0x410) + 0x7d);//This gives some kind of random address
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (void*)(adress), name.c_str(), name.length(), 0);//This works
```

How can I get the right address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this is an external project, and you're not injecting into the game process.  I assume this based on your usage of `WriteProcessMemory()`.  Conflicting this assumption is your usage of `GetCurrentProcess()` which is used to get a psuedo handle to the calling process.  In an external hack you don't need the calling process's handle.  Maybe you're internal and you're doing this in order to get the handle so you can later use WriteProcessMemory.  You should not be using `WriteProcessMemory()` in an internal hack

The reason your code doesn't work in this external project is because you're not de-referencing each pointer in your pointer chain.

Take this from your code:
`*(DWORD*)`

You're casting to a pointer type, and then de-referencing the pointer.  You're not executing inside the target process so this de-reference is acting on local memory instead of the game's target memory.  This code looks good if you were internal.

I can't be 100% in my answer as we don't have the declaration of `GetModuleBase()` but, your solution is to de-reference each pointer in the chain, which is after each offset except for the last one.  Externally you do this with  `ReadProcessMemory`, internally you use the same method you were already using.

Here are external and internal versions of a function that does this for you:

```cpp
//external
uintptr_t FindDMAAddy(HANDLE hProc, uintptr_t ptr, std::vector<unsigned int> offsets)
{
    uintptr_t addr = ptr;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < offsets.size(); ++i)
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (BYTE*)addr, &addr, sizeof(addr), 0);
        addr += offsets[i];
    }
    return addr;
}

//internal
uintptr_t FindDMAAddy(uintptr_t ptr, std::vector<unsigned int> offsets)
{
    uintptr_t addr = ptr;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < offsets.size() ; ++i)
    {
        addr = *(uintptr_t*)addr;
        addr += offsets[i];
    }
    return addr;
}


//external  
uintptr_2 addr1 = FindDMAAddy(hProc, moduleBase + 0x01E69FD8, {0x8, 0x410, 0x7d});
//internal
uintptr_t addr2 = FindDMAAddy(moduleBase + 0x01E69FD8, {0x8, 0x410, 0x7d});
```